# How to apply a calculation based on a formula in a data frame based on a number in a list?

Tags: python, optimization

I have the following data frame

```
columns = ['item', 'qty','provider','cost','return_rate','fullfill_rate']
sample_df = spark.createDataFrame([('A',1000,'A',50,0.01,0.9,),
                                ('A',1000,'B',40,0.02,0.6,),
                                ('A',1000,'C',45,0.01,0.5)], columns)



  input_table_df = (
      sample_df
      .toPandas()
    )
```

my formula is

```
cost_min = x * cost + ((1-fullfill_rate) * x) * cost + (return_rate* x) * cost
```

I want to apply this formula to each provider in the data frame based on a list and return the result of the equation. The list is shown below

```
input_array = [600, 150, 300]
```

so in the above example the formula will be

```
(600 * 50+ ((1-0.9) * 600) * 50+ (0.1 * 600) * 50) + 
(150 * 40+ ((1-0.6) * 150) * 40+ (0.02* 150) * 40) + 
(300 * 45+ ((1-0.5) * 300) * 45+ (0.01* 300) * 45)
```

I have tried the code below but this should iterate in each of the row in the list and the corresponding row in the data frame

```
input_array = [600, 150, 300]
cost = float(list(input_table_df['cost'])[0])
retun_rate = float(list(input_table_df['return_rate'])[0])
fullfill_rate = float(list(input_table_df['fullfill_rate'])[0])

cost_min = input_array[0] * cost + ((1-fullfill_rate) * input_array[0]) * cost + (retun_rate * input_array[0]) * cost

print(cost_min)
```

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on the DataFrame across axis 1 with a custom function that handles your formula. I wrapped this function with a function that can take in your input_array.

I make sure that the `input_array` matches the number of rows in the DataFrame to make sure you can correctly `apply` for formula. You will get an [AssertionError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#AssertionError) if your lengths don't match.

From there I [sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html?highlight=sum#pandas.Series.sum) the Series.

I created the pandas DataFrame directly here for ease of testing this solution, but feel free to replace this with your dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'item': ['A', 'A', 'A'],
    'qty': [1000, 1000, 1000],
    'provider': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'cost': [50, 40, 45],
    'return_rate': [0.01, 0.02, 0.01],
    'fulfill_rate': [0.9, 0.6, 0.5]
})


def apply_list(input_array):
    # Ensure input_array has enough rows to cover the DataFrame
    assert (len(input_array) == len(df))

    def calc_min_cost(row):
        item, qty, provider, cost, return_rate, fulfill_rate = row
        x = input_array[row.name] # Assumes Row Name is Index and matches index of input_array
        return x * cost + ((1 - fulfill_rate) * x) * cost + (return_rate * x) * cost

    return calc_min_cost

print(df.apply(apply_list([600, 150, 300]), axis=1).sum())
```

Naturally, you could also make the series a new column in your dataframe and then call sum on that if your row totals were important for some reason.

```py
df['cost_min'] = df.apply(apply_list([600, 150, 300]), axis=1)
print(df)
print(df['cost_min'].sum())
```

Another option is to make your input_array a new column in your dataframe.

```py
df['x'] = [600, 150, 300]


def calc_min_cost(row):
    item, qty, provider, cost, return_rate, fulfill_rate, x = row
    return (x * cost) + ((1 - fulfill_rate) * x * cost) + (return_rate * x * cost)


print(df.apply(calc_min_cost, axis=1).sum())
```

Then after you're done the computation you could delete the column to restore your DataFrame.

```
del df['x']
```